# Vuejs App still get 404 page after edit .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, vue.js, digital-ocean

I have a Vuejs App deployed at apache2 server in digitalocean , when you hit the url it forwards you to login page which is working fine and then automatic navigate me to dashboard page that have cards when I click on one of cards I get 404 page even after I edit my .htaccess file in dist

NOTE  the card route is domain.com/build

I tried .htaccess configuration from docs

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

and here is my virtual host configuration

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerAdmin email
        ServerName domain.com
        ServerAlias www.domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public_html/app/dist
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        ProxyPass /api/  http://localhost:8000/
        ProxyPassReverse /api/ http://localhost:8000/
RewriteEngine on
# Some rewrite rules in this file were disabled on your HTTPS site,
# because they have the potential to create redirection loops.

#RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.com
#RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: _"when I click on one of cards I get 404 page"_  this doesn't sound right at all. Even without URL rewriting, navigating by clicking should work fine. What does the _card_ code look like? What is it trying to do when you click and what URL is producing the 404?

Comment: I mean when I click on card it navigates me to route "domain.com/build" which navigates me to 404 page, I think it conflicts with apache virtual host proxy_pass. it will navigate me to page with this card details.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with virtual host file, the problem was in `apache2.conf` file in `/etc/apache2`. what I need is to change this part from

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to :

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

you need to change the AllowOverride attribute.